# How do you check the Gem Version in Ruby at Runtime?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is it possible to check the gem version of the currently loaded gem in a ruby/rails app?

During debugging, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
puts RubyGem.loaded_version(:active_support)
```

Anything like that exist?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
puts Gem.loaded_specs["activesupport"].version
```

Comment: And if you forgot what exactly the gem name is (e.g., libxml is named "libxml-ruby" but required as "xml/libxml") just remember that Gem.loaded_specs is a hash so you can do: `puts Gem.loaded_specs.keys.sort`

Comment: Or, if you would like an easy view of every loaded gem, `pp Gem.loaded_specs.map{|k,v| [k, v.version.to_s]}; nil`

Answer (score 39):

careful when comparing against `Gem.loaded_specs['mini_magick'].version` as it's not a `String` but a `Gem::Version` object !

the version string is accessible using `Gem.loaded_specs['mini_magick'].version.version` which is ugly and might not work as expected e.g. `'2.2' > '2.10'` !

the correct way to compare against a gem version is :

`Gem.loaded_specs['mini_magick'].version < Gem::Version.create('2.0')`

Comment: Thanks for the nifty create. +1 for that. Will .to_s work? In Rails console, adding .to_s to version gives a string. Gem.loaded_specs['mini_magick'].version.to_s
=> '2.2'. I don't know if this will be same inside the app.

Comment: yes that did not change `to_s` on a `Gem::Version` instance does return the same as `version` ... it's probably fine to use (you're assuming however that `to_s` will always be implemented that way)  but using `gem_version.version` is more explicit (although in my answer the `some.version.version` looks kind of ugly :)