# Why can I not locate a button using XPath?

Tags: xpath, watir

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Close List" class="tiny round success button" id="btnSaveCloseListPanel">
```

The following code does not work:

```
# browser.button(:value => "Close List").click   # does not work - timeout
browser.button(:xpath => "/html/body/center/div/div[9]/div[2]/input[2]").when_present.click
```

The error is:

```
Watir::Wait::TimeoutError:
timed out after 60 seconds
```

`when_present(300)` does not work.

I found the XPath using Firefox Developer Tools. I used the complete path to avoid any silly errors. I can find the same path manually in IE.

The component is a .NET MVC popup. I think it's called a "panel". The panel is a grandchild of the Internet Explorer tab.

The panel contains a datepicker, a dropdown, a text box, and 3 buttons. I can't find any of these using Watir. I can find anything in the panel's parent (obviously).

The underlying code does not seem to be aware that something actually doesn't exist. To prove that, I tested the following XPath, which is simply the above XPath with the middle bit removed:

```
browser.button(:xpath => "/html/body/center/div/input[2]").when_present.click
```

The error is "timeout", rather than "doesn't exist".

So, the code seems to be unaware that:

- input[1] does not exist, therefore input[2] cannot exist.
- div[2] does not exist.
- Therefore there's nothing left to search.

---

Added:

I'm changing the specific element that I want to find.

Reason: The button in my OP was at the foot of the panel. I was going cross-eyed trying to step upwards through hundreds of lines of HTML. Instead, I'm now using the first field in the panel. All the previous info is still the same.

The first field is a text field with datepicker.

The HTML is:

```
<input type="text" value="" style="width:82px!important;" readonly="readonly" name="ListDateClosed" id="ListDateClosed" class="hasDatepicker">
```

Using F12 in Firefox, the XPath is:

```
/html/body/center/div/div[1]/div[2]/input
```

But, now, with a lot less lines of HTML, I can clearly see that the `html` tag is not the topmost `html` tag in the file. The parent of `html` is `iframe`

I've never used `iframe` before.  Maybe this is what t0mppa was referring to in his comment to the first questiion.

As an experiment, I modified my XPath to:

```
browser.text_field(:xpath, '//iframe/html/body/center/div/div[1]/div[2]/input').when_present.set("01-Aug-2014")
```

But this times out, even with a 3-minute timeout.

Comment: Why don't you just use `input[@id='btnSaveCloseListPanel']`? Since all ids need to be unique within a page, it's the best way to describe the item you want to find.

Comment: Good point. But when I look in my code, I can see that line commented out with "doesn't work" (120 timeout)

Comment: Then the problem obviously is not about how you refer to the item, but whether it's visible, present, clickable, etc. in the browser, when your script tries to click it. Unless you provide more information about what's going on, it will be really hard to guess what kind of an issue there is.

Comment: Everything is visible. I sit looking at it for 5 minutes waiting for something to happen.

Comment: Can you access it using the same xpath, if you use a browser plugin like Selenium? Perhaps you need to choose the panel first somehow (like you have to swap in and out of frames), to tell the script not to look at the elements from the panels parent, but from the panel itself? Haven't used Watir myself, but that's how Webdriver works.

Comment: Note that with `when_present` the "timeout error" is essentially the same as a "doesn't exist error". It just means that the "doesn't exist error" occurred for 60 seconds.

Comment: +1 to @t0mppa for providing the clue that I need to fight my way into an `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the elements are in an iframe, there are two things to note:

- Unlike other elements types, you must always tell Watir when an element is in an iframe.
- XPaths (in the context of Watir) cannot be used to cross into frames.

Assuming that there is only 1 iframe on the page, you can explicitly tell Watir to search the first iframe by using the `iframe` method:

```
browser.iframe.text_field(:xpath, '//body/center/div/div[1]/div[2]/input').when_present.set("01-Aug-2014")
```

If there are multiple iframes, you can use the usual locators to be more specific about which iframe. For example, if the iframe had an id:

```
browser.iframe(id: 'iframe_id')
  .text_field(xpath: '//body/center/div/div[1]/div[2]/input')
  .when_present
  .set("01-Aug-2014")
```

Comment: I need the second iframe. 1) Edited ":" error for "id". 2) Inserted correct frame id. Got error: "syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting kEND", pointing to the dot preceding ".when_present". 3) Put everything on one line. Got error: "undefined method `iframe' for #"

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? `id:` is valid since it is the new hash notation. And are you using Watir-WebDriver or Watir-Classic?

Comment: 1) Updated to Ruby 2.1.3 + DevKit. Updated Watir and Watir-Classic. 

2) My setup does not like `id:` or `xpath:`. Error is "unexpected ':', expecting ')'". Multiline presentation complains about the first dot on the second line.

3) I use free community edition of TestWise, which does not support Watir-WebDriver. (Customer uses only IE.)

Comment: Sorry, I do not know why you would have those problems. The problems you are mentioning are pure Ruby syntax - ie have nothing to do with Watir.

Comment: Solved. If I put everything on the same line, I get no Ruby syntax errors. The error, as mentioned previously,  is `undefined method 'iframe' for #` In API for Watir-Classic, Method: `Watir::Container#iframe` there are examples. All examples use `browser.frame`, not `browser.iframe`

When I changed `iframe` to `frame` everything worked.

Comment: I'm no techie, but is it possible that the Watir-Classic API might be incorrect?

Comment: I am suspicious that your script is not actually using the latest version of Watir/Watir-Classic (even though you mention having updated it). The `iframe` method is definitely an alias of the `frame` method - see the [supported_elements.rb](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/blob/master/lib/watir-classic/supported_elements.rb#L103-L104) file. If you were using say version 2.0.4, which did not have the `iframe` method, then your exception would make sense.

Comment: ruby 2.1.3p242, watir 5.0.0, watir-classic 4.0.1. BTW: Thanks for all the support.

Comment: Where did you get those version numbers from? Did you verify that when running a script that those versions are actually being pulled in? I vaguely recall some people who were using RVM (Ruby Version Manager) and had installed the latest gems, but they were not being used by RVM (ie RVM was using the older versions).

Comment: I have 2 versions of Ruby:  1.9.3 and 2.1.3. I don't use RVM - I have Windows. Ruby 2.1.3 and 64-bit DevKit are on PATH, confirmed by `ruby -v`. In the `gems` folders, Watir and Classic have same version numbers for both 1.9.3 and 2.1.3:  W=5.0.0, W-C=4.0.1.  >> Did you verify that when running a script that those versions are actually being pulled in? Q: How do I do that?

Comment: Try checking the [gem version during run time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954279/how-do-you-check-the-gem-version-in-ruby-at-runtime).