# Rspec + shoulda test fails on accept_nested_attributes_for despite relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I'm writing a model test for my Applications model, which `accepts_nested_attributes_for(:user)`. Here's the test that's failing:

```
describe UserApplication, "associations" do
  it { should belong_to(:user) }
  it { should accept_nested_attributes_for(:user) }
end
```

And here's the model:

```
class UserApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
   #attr_accessible all the fields

   belongs_to :user
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

I'm using rspec with shoulda-matchers 2.8, and from my research this should all work fine. No spring or any other weirdness, either. Here's the error I'm seeing:

```
1) UserApplication association 
 Failure/Error: it { should accept_nested_attributes_for(:user) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `accept_nested_attributes_for' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2:0x007fec5c641a40>
 # ./spec/models/user_application_spec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this. Could this be some weird gem conflict shenanigans or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Can you try to upgrade you should-matcher to the latest version and try again? Can't see the docs for that specific version

Comment: @AnezioCampos Updating shoulda-matcher to 3.0 requires me to update activesupport to 4.0, which I can't do at the moment unfortunately. I'm stuck on rails 3.2 for time being.

Comment: This `it { should accept_nested_attributes_for(:user) }` should be `it { should accepts_nested_attributes_for(:user) }` (You are missing an `s` on `accepts`...
`
`

Comment: @Hackerman I thought it might have been that and saw some other threads that indicated that, but uunfortunately no dice. Just tested it and am getting the same result.

Comment: I would double check that you have shoulda loaded and that your version is correct.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2954632/1008891, for example.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin That was very enlightening. `Gem.loaded_specs["shoulda-matchers"].version` wound up returning `#<Gem::Version "1.0.0">`, which I was definitely not expecting. Looks like I've got some upgrading to do.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have to give credit to @PeterAlfvin for giving me the tools to see what was wrong. My gemfile specified `gem 'shoulda-matchers'` but that was only loading up version 1.0, which didn't have support for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. His suggestion, via https://stackoverflow.com/a/2954632/1008891 pointed me in the right direction. Specifying 2.8.0 fixed the problem without immediately breaking anything.